# Как активировать checkbox по нажатию клавиши enter?

Tags: c#, wpf

Собственно весь вопрос в заголовке. Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии Enter, галочка у checkbox активировалась?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот, только привяжи Event к Grid

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Grid_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if(e.Key == Key.Enter)
            {
                if (checkBox.IsChecked == true)
                    checkBox.IsChecked = false;
                else if (checkBox.IsChecked == false)
                    checkBox.IsChecked = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `checkBox.IsChecked = !checkBox.IsChecked` :)